# Magento Layered navigation filters creating thousands of 404 pages

Tags: magento, seo, google-search-console

I have magento site and was using layered  navigation extension.

This extension creates urls like

www.example.com/clothing/shopby/small-s/black/
(It filter result of clothing category by black color and small size)

www.example.com/mens/clothing/shopby/medium-m/blue/price--46-84/

(It filter result of mens/clothing category by blue color and medium size and price)

The word shopby is common when filter is applied.

google web master listed all such urls as separate urls.

so I added Noindex follow meta on head when filter is active

also

Disallow: /shopby/ in robots.txt

But google web master still listed thousands of 404 errors due to filters.

Now I have removed the extension from my site, but still there is thousand's of 404 errors.

How can I removed all these errors from google webmaster and these will not list again.

I want to remove all errors those are due to filter and contain word /shopby/ .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

For the 404 pages, you should have a custom 404 page, them make 301 redirect for the new pages if you have or to the homepage.

Also there is another way to block the parameter you have from Google webmaster tool by going to Crawl -> URL parameter, here you can choose which URLs to block and you can choose the type of this parameter (pagination,sorting,etc..)